# Validación Formulario

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, formularios, validación

Estoy intentando validar un Form y e conseguido que funcione pero cambie un id o clase o algo no se que de repente se me a jodido el código y no soy capaz de ver el error, y o es una tontería o ya después de tanto tiempo soy incapaz de verlo.

```
<form class="contacto" id="form1 " action="?action=<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? 'actualizar' : 'registrar'; ?>" method="POST" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
            <input  type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('acronimo') : ''; ?>" />

            <table style="width:500px;">
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-align:left;">Acronimo</th>
                    <td>
                        <input id="acronimo"  class="form-control"  type="text" name="acronimo"  value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('acronimo') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;"  />
                    </td>
                    <th style="text-align:left;">Categoria</th>
                    <td>
                        <input id="categoria"  class="form-control" type="text" name="categoria"  value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('categoria') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" />
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-align:left;">Registro Calidad</th>
                    <td>
                        <select class="form-control" id="registro_calidad" name="registro_calidad">
                            <option value=""><?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('registro_calidad') : ''; ?></option>
                            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                            <option value="No">No</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>                        
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" class="boton">Guardar</button></td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <form action="index.php">
                            <input class="btn btn-primary boton" type="reset" value="Limpiar" />
                        </form></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

Y este el código:

```
$(function() {

$(".boton").click(function(){
    $(".error").fadeOut().remove();

    if ($(".acronimo").val() == "") {
        $(".acronimo").focus().after('<span class="error">Ingrese su nombre</span>');
        return false;
    }

    if ($(".categoria").val() == "") {
        $(".categoria").focus().after('<span class="error">Ingrese un asunto</span>');
        return false;
    }

});
$(".acronimo, .categoria").bind('blur keyup', function(){
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
        $('.error').fadeOut();
        return false;
    }
});
```

});

Comment: El html tiene un error de sintaxis. Estás cerrando la etiqueta input con una etiqueta button. Cabe mencionar que las preguntas sobre código que no funciona deben seguir los lineamientos de [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al parecer borraste parte del código ***html***

Código actual:

```
<input type="submit" class="boton">
Guardar</button>
</td>
```

Código correcto:

```
<input type="submit" class="boton">
<button>Guardar</button>
</td>
```

o tal vez querías colocar:

```
<input type="submit" class="boton" 
value="Guardar" />
</td>
```

Aqui te dejo el codigo de como deberia quedar:

```js
$(function() {

$(".boton").click(function(){
    $(".error").fadeOut().remove();

    if ($(".acronimo").val() == "") {
        $(".acronimo").focus().after('<span class="error">Ingrese su nombre</span>');
        return false;
    }

    if ($(".categoria").val() == "") {
        $(".categoria").focus().after('<span class="error">Ingrese un asunto</span>');
        return false;
    }

});
$(".acronimo, .categoria").bind('blur keyup', function(){
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
        $('.error').fadeOut();
        return false;
    }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="contacto" id="form1 " action="?action=<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? 'actualizar' : 'registrar'; ?>" method="POST" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
            <input  type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('acronimo') : ''; ?>" />

            <table style="width:500px;">
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-align:left;">Acronimo</th>
                    <td>
                        <input id="acronimo"  class="form-control"  type="text" name="acronimo"  value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('acronimo') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;"  />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-align:left;">Categoria</th>
                    <td>
                        <input id="categoria"  class="form-control" type="text" name="categoria"  value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('categoria') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" />
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-align:left;">Registro Calidad</th>
                    <td>
                        <select class="form-control" id="registro_calidad" name="registro_calidad">
                            <option value=""><?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('registro_calidad') : ''; ?></option>
                            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                            <option value="No">No</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>                        
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" class="boton" value="Guardar" />
                        <form action="index.php">
                            <input class="btn btn-primary boton" type="reset" value="Limpiar" />
                        </form></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

Comment: muchas gracias, voy a  revisarlo, por cierto no encuentro ninguna web para crear variables de validacion en Ajax únicamente encontré esta variable: ---var email = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/; --- Como podría crear una variable para acronimo que solo pueda tener 3 caracteres y letras mayúsculas?

Comment: Se llaman **expresiones regulares**, en el siguiente [link](https://regexone.com/) podras encontrar un exelente tutorial, la siguiente expresión `/^[A-Z]{3}$/` te permite validar una entrada con valores que van desde la `A` hasta la `Z` `[A-Z]` y que sean de 3 caracteres `{3}` desde el principio `[` hasta el final `$`

Comment: Ahora funciona todo perfecto con sus validaciones y el form como me aconsejastes tio, muchisimas gracias! Un saludo.

Comment: Por cierto o estoy ciego, o en esa pág donde viene para poder hacer lo mismo con un `select option`?